# Auto populate Title field with current date

Tags: date, title

Is there a way to auto populate the Title field with current date?
Basically Im wondering if the Title field can be auto- filled in with the current date when creating a new entry. EE 6

Comment: As a general rule you will get a more informative answer to your question if you follow a couple of simple principles: give some details of the version of EE that you are working with (and possibly what hosting environment); and give some contextual information about the issue you are having - for example in this case is this when entering / editing a channel entry in the Control Panel or some other circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

Install the free [MX CP CSS & JS](https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/mx-cp-css-js) add-on and add the following code to the JS field in the settings of the add-on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var currentDate = Date.now();
    var today = new Date(currentDate);
    var dateString = today.toLocaleDateString();
    var titleField = $('input[name="title"]');
    var url = $(location).attr('href');

    if(titleField.length && url.indexOf('/cp/publish/create/') > 0) {
        titleField.val(dateString  + " ");
    }
});
```

It will populate the title field with the current date with a trailing space.